# Expand DIV width that is next to a floated div

Tags: css, css-float

I want to expand the width of a DIV that is next to a right floated div.

If that other div is left floated, I have no problem:
[http://jsfiddle.net/ykyVv/](http://jsfiddle.net/FMyjU/)

But I don't know how to do it if the other div is floated to the right:
http://jsfiddle.net/FMyjU/
(notice that the divs are not next to each other, I also tried to add float:left to the first div but then it doesn't expand anymore)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/MYRde/

Answer (score 2):

Put the second division before the first one. You might also want to add a margin-right to the `div1` which is equivalent to the width of the right-floated one.
A general rule of floating elements: right **then** left.

[Updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FMyjU/1/) or
[Fiddle with right margin.](http://jsfiddle.net/FMyjU/2/)

Comment: thank you, notice that the version of Matt Wolfe renders a little bit better (the borders in his version don't overlap)